# How to calculate number of chars common to two strings?

Tags: ruby

How would you calculate the intersection of characters between two strings?

For example (assuming we would have a method called `String.intersection`):

```
"abc".intersection("ab") = 2
"hello".intersection("hallo") = 4
```

Ok, boys and girls, thanks for your massive feedback. Some more examples:

```
"aaa".intersection("a") = 1
"foo".intersection("bar") = 0
"abc".intersection("bc") = 2
"abc".intersection("ac") = 2
"abba".intersection("aa") = 2
```

Some more notes:
Wikipedia defines [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) as follows:

> Intersection of the sets A and B,
>   denoted A ∩ B, is the set of all
>   objects that are members of both A and
>   B. The intersection of {1, 2, 3} and
>   {2, 3, 4} is the set {2, 3}

Comment: What about `"abc".intersection("bc")`, `"abc".intersection("ac")`, etc.?

Comment: i love how many correct solutions there are to this lol

Comment: @Ascherer: basically because the question is ambiguous as it stands right now.

Comment: Citation of **intersection on sets** is unnecessary. That is what everyone is clear about. Rather, it is your definition of **intersection on strings** that is ambiguous.

Comment: Ok. Just for the sake of completeness ... ;-)

Comment: To get the *unique* characters common to 2 (or more) strings, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702088/function-that-returns-number-of-characters-in-common-in-rails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This passes all your described test cases:

```
class String
  def intersection(other)
    str = self.dup
    other.split(//).inject(0) do |sum, char|
      sum += 1 if str.sub!(char,'')
      sum
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In ruby 1.9, you can replace `split(//)` with `chars`.

Comment: @sawa: Old habits die hard, plus this way it should work in 1.8 and 1.9., but you are right of course.

Comment: Use `count` rather than `inject`.

Comment: Did you see OP's comment on the `count` answer below?

Answer (score 8):

Use [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001203):

```
irb(main):001:0> "hello".count("hallo")
=> 4
irb(main):002:0> "abc".count("ab")
=> 2
```

Comment: Keep in mind the question says "number of chars common", not "number of occurences of common chars".  As I said in my answer, `'aaa'.count('a')` gives `3`, when the OP might want `1` as the result.  I guess we'll know what the OP meant when he chooses the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use something like:

```
'abc'.split('') & 'ab'.split('') #=> ["a", "b"]
'hello'.split('') & 'yellow'.split('') #=> ["e", "l", "o"]
```

If you want a method to do it:

```
class String
  def intersection(other)
    self.split('') & other.split('')
  end
end
'hello'.intersection('yellow') #=> ["e", "l", "o"]
'now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country'.intersection('jackdaws love my giant sphinx of quartz')
=> ["n", "o", "w", " ", "i", "s", "t", "h", "e", "m", "f", "r", "a", "l", "g", "d", "c", "u", "y"]
```

To get the number of characters in common just tack on .size:

```
'hello'.intersection('yellow').size #=> 3
```

If you want the count of all matching common characters:

```
'hello'.count('hello'.intersection('yellow').join) #=> 4
```

Traditionally we'd do it by building a hash using each character in the first string, along with a counter, then walk through the second string incrementing the counter for each common character:

```
asdf = Hash[*'hello'.split('').map{ |s| [s, 0]}.flatten] #=> {"l"=>0, "o"=>0, "e"=>0, "h"=>0}
'yellow'.split('').each{ |s| asdf[s] += 1 if (asdf.key?(s)) }
asdf #=> {"l"=>2, "o"=>1, "e"=>1, "h"=>0}
```

The number of common characters:

```
asdf.select{ |n,v| v > 0 }.size #=> 3
```

The count of the common characters:

```
asdf.values.inject(0){ |m,i| m += i } #=> 4
```

Comment: `"hello".intersection("hallo").size #=> 3`, but it's 4 in the question

Answer (score 4):

Basically summing up the minimum number of occurences of each common character:

```
class String
  def intersection(compared_to)
    common_chars = (self.split('') & compared_to.split(''))
    common_chars.inject(0) { |result, char|
      result + [self.count(char), compared_to.count(char)].min
    }
  end
end
```

Results:

```
"abc".intersection("ab")      #=> 2
"hello".intersection("hallo") #=> 4
"aaa".intersection("a")       #=> 1
"foo".intersection("bar")     #=> 0
"abc".intersection("bc")      #=> 2
"abc".intersection("ac")      #=> 2
"abba".intersection("aa")     #=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using scan method to convert string into array and using `&` intersection operator you can do like this...

```
('abd'.scan(/./) & 'abc'.scan(/./)).length
```

Comment: More clear way to convert it into array of chars: `"abc".chars.to_a`

Comment: Or use `'abc'.split('')` which is more idiomatic.

Comment: This doesn't work for the `"abba".intersection("aa") = 2` case.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest for me is the utilize the array intersection operator `&` like below

```
class String
  def intersection(other)
    str = self.dup
    str.chars & other.chars
  end
end
```

usage like

```
"hello".intersection("hiho") // => ['h', '0']
"hello".intersection("hiho").size // => 2
```