# Function that returns number of characters in common in rails

Tags: ruby, string

Is there any function in ruby that compares two strings and returns the number of characters they have in common?

Comment: I know of no such built-in method, but you could write one if you define your problem space a bit better.  Can you give some examples?  And I assume this isn't homework?  :)

Comment: It isn't homework :) I want to implemnt jaro-winkler algorithm and the first step is to compute m, where m is the number of matching characters in the same positions(i forget to mention this in my question). For example for 'CRATE' an 'TRACE' m is 3 (they have R, A, E in common  positions: 1, 2 and 3). But i suppose i'll have do it by myself

Comment: If that is the case, then this is an XY-problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting:

```
s1 = "abacad"
s2 = "bagfa"
```

You can write:

```
(s1.chars & s2.chars).size
  #=> 2
```

If you want to count duplicates:

```
s1.chars.uniq.reduce(0) { |cnt,c| cnt + [s1.count(c), s2.count(c)].min }
  #=> 3
```

**Edit1:** After reading @ChrisHeald's comment I see the OP added an additional requirement in a comment: that matching characters occupy the same positions. In that case it's even easier:

```
s1.chars.zip(s2[0,[s1.size, s2.size].min].chars).count { |c1,c2| c1==c2 }
  #=> 1
```

I was obliged to modify what I initially had, as @ChrisHeald pointed out a problem. Unfortunately, the correction brought with it an uglification (as well as a temporary string and yet another temporary array).

We have

```
a = s1.chars.zip(s2.chars)
  #=> [["a", "b"], ["b", "a"], ["a", "g"], ["c", "f"], ["a", "a"], ["d", nil]]
a.count { |c1,c2| c1==c2 } 
  #=> 1
```

**Edit2:**

To avoid the creation of intermediate arrays:

```
[s1.size, s2.size].min.times.count { |i| s1[i] == s2[i] }
  #=> 1
```

Comment: This will return all characters in common, rather than all common characters in the same position. `s1 = "ab"; s2 = "ba"` gives you *m* of 2, when it should be 0.

Comment: @Chris, I was going by the question, not having noticed the additional information in the OP's comment. (Don't people notice the "edit" button?) I may add something.

Comment: Upvoted for a valid solution, but I do want to point out that this will create n+1 intermediate arrays (where n is the string length) and will fail when the strings are of mismatched sizes; for string processing, these probably aren't desirable traits.

Comment: @ChrisHeald, coincident with your last comment I had edited to use `count`. Strings of different lengths (as in my example) are not a problem, but yes, `zip` creates a temp array.

Comment: Not just one temp array, one temp array per character pair and then a containing array. :) - Zip will fail if s2 is longer than s1, though - `[1].zip([1,2]) => [[1, 1]]`

Comment: @ChrisHeald, er, I forgot about `zip's` behaviour when the shorter array is first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one, but it's trivial to write one:

```
def matching_chars(str1, str2)
  chars, index = str2.chars, -1
  str1.chars.count {|c| chars[index += 1] == c }
end
```

Just iterate over one string's characters and count the number of times that it matches the character in the other string's position.