# Two strings being almost equal

Tags: ruby, string

I define that two strings are *almost equal* if:

1. they have the same length, or
2. their length differs by one, and the strings differ by a single character.

These two strings are almost equal:

```
HOW DO YOU
HO DO YOU
```

as are these:

```
abcdef
bcdef
```

But these strings are not almost equal:

```
Almost
Anost
```

nor are these:

```
Almost
Aomst
```

I have this function that I attempted to make it tell if two strings are almost equal:

```
def str_almost_equal(a, b)
  a.downcase == b.downcase || (a.size == b.size && a.downcase.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == b.downcase[i]}.count(false) == 1)
end
```

Calling the code above with `"aaa"` and `"aab"` evaluates to `true`.

How do I expand my function so that strings are almost equal if in addition to the above, the strings lengths differ by only one and the characters are identical except for one?

Comment: Why do you have `downcase` in the code? It seems to mess up your whole intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order was not an issue, then you could just compute set difference of the characters:

```
def str_almost_equal(a, b)
  shortest, longest = [a.chars,b.chars].minmax_by(&:length)
  (longest - shortest).length == 1
end
```

However, your last test indicates that order is indeed significant. So this is more of a [longest common subsequence](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence) problem with these characteristics:

- The LCS must be equal to the smaller string (in other words, the small string must be completely contained within the larger string, but not necessarily consecutive)
- The larger string must be larger by exactly one character

So, given an `lcs` function, you can do this:

```
def str_almost_equal(a, b)
  shortest, longest = [a,b].minmax_by(&:length)
  lcs(a,b) == shortest && longest.length - shortest.length == 1
end
```

You can find `lcs` functions at the above link. Here is one:

```
def lcs(xstr, ystr)
  return "" if xstr.empty? || ystr.empty?

  x, xs, y, ys = xstr[0..0], xstr[1..-1], ystr[0..0], ystr[1..-1]
  if x == y
    x + lcs(xs, ys)
  else
    [lcs(xstr, ys), lcs(xs, ystr)].max_by {|x| x.size}
  end
end
```

There is also the `diff-lcs` gem you can look into.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "fuzzy-string-match" gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'fuzzy-string-match'
```

It's really easy to use:

```
2.2.7 :001 > require 'fuzzystringmatch'
 => true 
2.2.7 :002 >     jarow = FuzzyStringMatch::JaroWinkler.create(:pure)
 => #<FuzzyStringMatch::JaroWinklerPure:0x007fa08c4d8710> 
2.2.7 :003 > jarow.getDistance('Almost', 'Aomst')
 => 0.8900000000000001 
2.2.7 :004 > jarow.getDistance('Almost', 'Anost')
 => 0.8400000000000001 
2.2.7 :005 > jarow.getDistance('Almost', 'Almost')
 => 1.0
```

I use it for fuzzy string matching and it's great.  In my case, I'm matching file names against song titles, and I do a cartesian join (basically, match every filename against every title) and then take the top hits for each one, at least when they're past a certain threshold.

Comment: I tried including the "fuzzy-string-match" gem in my Gemfile, but got the error, "Could not find gem 'fuzzystringmatch' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine"

Comment: You have to run bundle to add the gem.  You can read the docs for that.

Comment: Looking at other answers - please don't reinvent this wheel unless it's an academic exercise.  The Jaro/Winkler algorithm is as good as they come and it's already been coded.  Use it and solve a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the intersection of the two strings.

check this link out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6074842/8202380) that provides the number of same characters between two strings.

You could check the length of the longest string, to the number of characters that they intersect.

E.g. if the longer string is of length n, the intersection should be n-1 to be "almost" equal

Comment: This doesn't work though.  Per the function you listed "abc".intersection("ba") results in a non-nil value but per my definition they are not almost equal.  "abc" is "almost" equal to "ab" and almost equal to "ac" but NOT almost equal to "ca" or "ba".  Ordering is important.